# Need to set multiple onclicklisteners for multiple gridviews in single class

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have an icon picker that lets users select icons to change on homescreen.

I wanted to divide up my gridviews so i could put them into categories ie apps, games folders etc.

I am able to get the view right and display them correctly but the onclick listener is not working. when the icon is clicked it won't bring back the icon.

Also it seems i may be overworking this? Do i really have to set 2 adapters for the gridviews? on my logcat i get a ton of dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed ....... lines that happen when this class is launched.

**This is my icons2 class**

```
package bigdx.clean.multi;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import bigdx.clean.multi.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Icons2 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public Uri CONTENT_URI;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
        setContentView(R.layout.icon_picker);

        ExpandableHeightGridView g=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_folders);
        g.setExpanded(true);
        g.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        g.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize));
        g.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        ExpandableHeightGridView g2=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_apps);
        g2.setExpanded(true);
        g2.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        g2.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter2(this, iconSize));
        g2.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        this.CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + IconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());

    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                String str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                setResult(-1, new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(this.CONTENT_URI, str)));
                finish();
              }

    class IconsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private int mIconSize;
        private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;

        public IconsAdapter(Context mContext, int iconsize) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mIconSize = iconsize;
                  loadIcons();
                }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }

        private void loadIcons() {
            mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            final Resources resources = getResources();
            final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();

            addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_folders);
        }
        private void addIcons(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
            final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
            for (String extra : extras) {
                int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
                if (res != 0) {
                    final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra,"drawable", packageName);
                    if (thumbRes != 0) {
                        mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    class IconsAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private int mIconSize;
        private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;

        public IconsAdapter2(Context mContext, int iconsize) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mIconSize = iconsize;
                  loadIcons();
                }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }

        private void loadIcons() {
            mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            final Resources resources = getResources();
            final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();

            addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_apps);
        }
        private void addIcons(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
            final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
            for (String extra : extras) {
                int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
                if (res != 0) {
                    final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra,"drawable", packageName);
                    if (thumbRes != 0) {
                        mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is my iconpicker layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back_dark" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="75dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/text_divider"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/icon_folders"
                android:textColor="@color/divider"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <bigdx.clean.multi.ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:id="@+id/icon_grid_folders"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/icon_grid_folders"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/text_divider"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/icon_apps"
                android:textColor="@color/divider"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <bigdx.clean.multi.ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:id="@+id/icon_grid_apps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/semiblack"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/theme_header2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Updated icons2 class

```
package bigdx.clean.multi;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import bigdx.clean.multi.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Intent.ShortcutIconResource;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Icons extends Activity {
    private static final String ACTION_ADW_PICK_ICON="org.adw.launcher.icons.ACTION_PICK_ICON";
    private static final String ACTION_ADW_PICK_RESOURCE="org.adw.launcher.icons.ACTION_PICK_ICON_RESOURCE";
    private boolean mPickerMode=false;
    private boolean mResourceMode=false;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
        setContentView(R.layout.icon_picker);

        if(getIntent().getAction().equals(ACTION_ADW_PICK_ICON)){
            mPickerMode=true;
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra(ACTION_ADW_PICK_RESOURCE)){
            mResourceMode=true;
        }

        ExpandableHeightGridView g=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_folders);
        ExpandableHeightGridView g2=(ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid_apps);
        g.setExpanded(true);
        g2.setExpanded(true);
        g.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g.getId()));
        g2.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize, g2.getId()));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mPickerMode){
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    if(!mResourceMode){
                        Bitmap bitmap=null;
                        try{
                            bitmap=(Bitmap) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        if(bitmap!=null){
                            intent.putExtra("icon",bitmap);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        }else{
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                        }
                    }else{
                        ShortcutIconResource res=((IconsAdapter)adapterView.getAdapter()).getResource(position);
                        if(res!=null){
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, res);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        }else{
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                        }
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        g2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mPickerMode){
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    if(!mResourceMode){
                        Bitmap bitmap=null;
                        try{
                            bitmap=(Bitmap) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        if(bitmap!=null){
                            intent.putExtra("icon",bitmap);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        }else{
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                        }
                    }else{
                        ShortcutIconResource res=((IconsAdapter)adapterView.getAdapter()).getResource(position);
                        if(res!=null){
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, res);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        }else{
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                        }
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private class IconsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private int mIconSize;
        private int mG;

        public IconsAdapter(Context mContext, int iconsize, int g) {
            super();
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mIconSize = iconsize;
            this.mG = g;
            loadIcons();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbs.size();
        }

        public ShortcutIconResource getResource(int position){
            return ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(Icons.this,
                    mThumbs.get(position));
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mThumbs.get(position), opts);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }

        private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void loadIcons() {
            mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            final Resources resources = getResources();
            final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();

            switch (mG){
            case R.id.icon_grid_folders:
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_folders);
            case R.id.icon_grid_apps:
                addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack_apps);
            }


        }
        private void addIcons(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
            final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
            for (String extra : extras) {
                int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
                if (res != 0) {
                    final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra,"drawable", packageName);
                    if (thumbRes != 0) {
                        mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I have the icons clickable, but need to set each gridview with one adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let the IDE create the function itself.
Look like you wrote it by yourself as I see you don't have the @Override annotation.

try delete your onItemClick function and let the eclipse/intellij/whatever it is to do it for you.
you should see it with the annotation:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
```

If this still not working (can't see why not) try it anonymously:

```
g.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // your logic here...
        }
    });
```

For the second question, seems that the system using lots of memory when you're loading and sets image resource. I would suggest you to decode bitmap and resize them to fit to fit the screen.

good luck

Comment: I updated my original post with another onItemClick method i should have been using. I think this is what you were talking about to save memory?  With this function using the override notation i am getting an error on [ShortcutIconResource res=((IconsAdapter)adapterView.getAdapter()).getResource(position);] says IconsAdapter2 cannot be cast to IconsAdapter. This is the problem im having. because i have 2 gridviews i created 2 adapters. how to i implement them both on the onClickListener?

Comment: That's another issue :) you need to create only ONE BaseAdapter for g and g2. and use .setAdapter(new IconAdapter(..)) for both of them

Comment: The problem is that the private void loadIcons() method loads icons from different arrays for each gridview. how can i implement a loadicons() method for each gridview in same adapter?

Comment: you can pass to the IconsAdapter constructor the gridView id and in the constructor do the logic, I would suggest you to save the id as a member in the nested BaseAdapter class if you'll have to do some different logic in the getView(...) or other overrided functions.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking. Im playing around with it and can seem to figure out howto pass the arguments. I know i need to do a if then or case (because i will actually have 4 sections is the reason the case might work better) so i would do if/then OR case gridview id = g add icons(blah blah blah) But how to i pass those arguments. Thanks you so much for you help!

Comment: just saw your last message in full. How can i pass the gridview id to the base adapter class? i know it goes here [public IconsAdapter(Context mContext, int iconsize)] and comes from here [IconsAdapter adapter=new IconsAdapter(this,iconSize);] but how do i set the multiple gridview ids to those arguments?

Comment: pass it to the constructor: g.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(this, iconSize,g.getId())); .. , in the constructor you'll get another variable as integer. the same one as R.id.icon_grid_folders or icon_grid_apps. from there it's up to you what to do with it. good luck.

Comment: Thank you again for all you help. I have the arguments and the case statement setup and working. I click the icon and it sets it. Please give advice for one more issue. Since i am using one adapter both arrays from loadicons function are being loaded to both gridviews. I need each array to load separate gridviews.

Comment: you are doing it correctly. you have only one Array (mThumbs) and it is being load only once from your switch(mG).

Comment: Still cant figure it out but don't want to bother you anymore than i have to. I moved the [mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();] under both the cases but still isnt loading the gridviews right. Thanks again for your time and i accepted your answer as it did get me very close